# A regex / json-schema pattern for an IPFS CID?

Tags: regex, jsonschema, ipfs

I'd like to include a pattern for an ipfs content identifier ([CID](https://docs.ipfs.io/concepts/content-addressing/)) in a json schema. To do this, I need to create a regex to match them.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "$id": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "Example schema with an ipfs CID",
    { "type": "object",
      "properties": {
          "ipfs":  { "type": "string","pattern": "<CID regex here>"}
      }
}
```

**What is a good way to do a regex for an IPFS CID?**

Answer (score 3):

For [CIDv0](https://github.com/multiformats/cid#cidv0):

> the multibase of the string representation is always base58btc

E.g. QmcRD4wkPPi6dig81r5sLj9Zm1gDCL4zgpEj9CfuRrGbzF

```
Qm[1-9A-Za-z]{44}[^OIl]
```

seems to work

For [CIDv1](https://github.com/multiformats/cid#cidv1), the encoding changes conditional on the [first character](https://github.com/multiformats/multibase#multibase-table) (below are encodings with default status):

```
> *encoding*             *code*                               
> identity               0x00
> base16                 f
> base16upper            F
> hexadecimal base32     b
> base32upper            B
> base58btc              z
> base64                 m   
> base64url              u
> base64urlpad           U
```

e.g. `bafybeigrf2dwtpjkiovnigysyto3d55opf6qkdikx6d65onrqnfzwgdkfa`

has hexadecimal base32 encoding after the `b`

This means that the regex would have to have a conditional element based on the first character.

Also, I think I'm right to say that the length of a CIDv1 changes based on the selected hash algorithm. This answer is constrained to hash algorithms with 256 bit output only.

This approach splits up the regex with OR `|` operators:

```
Qm[1-9A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z]{44,}|b[A-Za-z2-7]{58,}|B[A-Z2-7]{58,}|z[1-9A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z]{48,}|F[0-9A-F]{50,}
```

Perhaps there is a better way, though.

Comment: Highly recommend you to use start / end of the string (^$) operators to avoid security vulnerabilities.

`^(Qm[1-9A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z]{44,}|b[A-Za-z2-7]{58,}|B[A-Z2-7]{58,}|z[1-9A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z]{48,}|F[0-9A-F]{50,})$`

Comment: there must be *some* reasonable upper limit, even though the comment adds ^ and $ it is still possible to put any length in, and I don't think there will be infinitely long hashes - so what is this upper limit?

Comment: @0x10 seems that SHA512/whirlpool are commonly used algs with longest output (of 512 bit), so upper limit (hex encoding) would be 128 char.

Comment: Here's regex with folders support for urls like this https://ipfs.io/ipfs/bafybeieyb46miigq4ib6bzfaci2ufxbijqfipjax367ens4zsb765btme4/image.jpeg (still xss-safe tho):

`^ipfs:\/\/(Qm[1-9A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z]{44,}|b[A-Za-z2-7]{58,}|B[A-Z2-7]{58,}|z[1-9A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z]{48,}|F[0-9A-F]{50,})(\/(\d|\w|\.)+)*$`

Comment: UPD chars after CID treated as url stuff: slug/query/hash `^ipfs:\/\/(Qm[1-9A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z]{44,}|b[A-Za-z2-7]{58,}|B[A-Z2-7]{58,}|z[1-9A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z]{48,}|F[0-9A-F]{50,})([/?#][-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_+.~#?&//=]*)*$`. Query use case: https://ipfs.io/ipfs/Qmc89mb8sHt3zW1wwCuVhKMniVcKc2KBf5AgGT4YESp5Ni/?fxhash=opCrh7H6qZKKhL3Kdu3dP5EbMCLF3DAAq2sxKRp8TwoyHHpXL3o